# Django function working in Chrome,Opera and Microsoft Edge but not in FireFox

Tags: django

I have written a delete function,when user click logout button it triggers ajax call which calls delete function and destroys session.I am saving my session in file. But problem is my code is working fine in different browsers otherthan Firefox, in firefox when i clcik logout button it performs the task but terminate the performance abnormally which out redirecting back to the home page. Logout operation doesnt take me back to the `localhost:8000`,instead of that it stays in `localhost:8000/logout`. But same code working fine on other browsers and redirecting back to home page successfully!

```
def logout(request):
    if request.session.has_key:
        request.session.delete()
    else:
        pass
    return JsonResponse({'logout':True,'redirect_url': reverse('sanjh:home')})


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#logout-anchor').click(function(event){
        console.log('hi-you are logged out')

        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/logout',
            success: function(res) {
            console.log(res);
            window.location = res.redirect_url;

            }
        })
        })
    })
</script>]
```

[image]

Comment: problem not with the django, it's with the frontend code..

Comment: @AvinashRaj what's wrong in frontend code? Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to check `if request.session.has_key` - `has_key` is a method so will always evaluate to `True`. Calling `request.session.delete()` is not how you log a user out. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-out) on how to do it properly.

Comment: @Alasdair actually i am not using django auth,so i cant use logout/login function to do the authentication, therefore i am using session!when user logs in i create session then when logs out it deletes the session.

Comment: Even in that case, the `if request.session.has_key` check does not make sense.

Comment: @Alasdair i have changed now that to if ` request.session.session_key`,still its works abnormally on firefox..

Comment: I was just pointing out the issue with the Django code. As AvinashRaj said, the problem in FireFox is probably in the JavaScript. I can't help with that.